# Image of the moment map

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry

Let $(M^{2n}, \omega ,\mathbb T)$ be non-compact symplectic manifold with an effective and Hamiltonian torus $\mathbb T$-action.

Suppose its moment map $\mu$ is proper and the fixed point set of $\mathbb T$ is compact. Can we prove that the image $\mu(M)$ is a polyhedron? That is, $\mu(M)$ is the intersection of finitely-many half-spaces.

Comment: By "intersection of finite half-spaces" you mean a finite intersection of half spaces, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The claim is incorrect - We'll construct a non-compact symplectic toric manifold with an empty fixed point set and a proper momentum map, whose image is an infinite intersection of half-spaces (which cannot be made finite).

Karshon and Lerman (see citation below) have generalized Delzant classification to non-compact toric manifolds.
In Example 6.9 in their paper, they constructed a non-compact symplectic toric manifold $(M, \omega, \mu)$, with a proper momentum map $\mu$, whose image is an infinite intersection of half-spaces (which cannot be made finite).

This does not answer your question yet, since the space they constructed has infinitely many vertices, which corresponds to fixed points of the action, so the fixed points set is not compact. However, we can use this space to construct our wanted space.

Take the non-compact symplectic toric manifold $(\mathbb{R}\times S^1, dh\wedge d\theta, h)$. This is a symplectic cylinder, with an Hamiltonian $S^1$ action which rotates the cylinder around its axis. Note that it has no fixed points. The product $(M, \omega, \mu) \times (\mathbb{R}\times S^1, dh\wedge d\theta, h)$ is again a non-compact symplectic toric manifold, but with no fixed points. The map $\mu \times h$ is proper, and its image is $\mu(M) \times \mathbb{R}$ which is again an infinite intersection of half-spaces (which cannot be made finite).

Y. Karshon and E. Lerman, Non-compact symplectic toric manifolds, SIGMA Symmetry Integrability Geom. Methods Appl. 11 (2015), Paper 055, 37, DOI 10.3842/SIGMA.2015.055. MR3371718  ([link to arxiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.2891))